# sqllite ionic 2 cannot read property push of undefined

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

```
    export class SearchHistoryList {

  public names:[Object];



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public productServiceProvider: ProductsServiceProvider, private sqlite: SQLite) {
    this.getDBData();

  }

  private getDBData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM searchHistory',[])
        .then(res => {
          if (res.rows.length > 0) {
            for(let i=0; i <res.rows.length; i++) {

              this.names.push({
                id: res.item(i).rowid,
                name: res.item(i).searchItem,
                time: res.item(i).date
              });
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to read my database and create an array of objects that I want to use with ngFor on my page. I am getting **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"**. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Try `names: Object[] = []`.

Comment: res.item is not a function????

Comment: Did not work any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: res.rows.item(i).rowid got itt small typo. Thanks Y'all